# Hibernate Ajax Получение обновленный данных после добавления

Tags: ajax, hibernate, form, jsf, primefaces

Здравствуйте :)
Итак, есть форма с отправкой комментариев.
`Чего хочу` - пользователь вводит текст комментария, отправляет, без перезагрузки страницы отображается новый список комментариев, в котором верхний - только что отправленный. Происходит с помощью технологии `AJAX`. Когда было на чистом `JDBC` - всё работало как надо. Сейчас переписываю на `Hibernate` - отображается старый список после отправки формы, если перезагрузить страницу, то список - обновленный. Использую JSF - реализация `PrimeFaces`

Форма отправки:
`<h:form>`

```
<p:inputTextarea id="textResponse" value="#{currentUser.response}" 
                 requiredMessage="!" 
                 placeholder="Напишите отзыв">
    <f:validateRequired />   
</p:inputTextarea>
<h:message id="message_textResponse" for="textResponse" style="color:red"/>

<h:commandButton class="reg_button" action="#{currentUser.addResponse}" value="Отправить">
    <f:ajax execute="textResponse" render="@form" />
</h:commandButton>

<c:forEach var="resp" items="#{initIndex.resps}">
    <table class="responseTable">
        <tr><td class="oneLine">#{resp.users.name} #{resp.users.family}</td>
            <td class="dateLine">#{resp.date.toString()}</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="responseLine" colspan="2">#{resp.text}</td></tr>
    </table>
</c:forEach>
```

`</h:form>`

Далее есть 2 `Managed Bean`-а.
`currentUser`:

`

```
@Named(value = "currentUser")
@SessionScoped
public class UsersBean implements Serializable {
 private Integer id = -1;   

 private String response;
 ResponseDAO respDAO;


/**
 * Creates a new instance of UsersBean
 */
public UsersBean() {
      respDAO = new ResponseDAO();
}


public void addResponse() {
    if (id != -1) {
        respDAO.addResponse(id, response);
    }

    response = "";
}

 /**
 * геттеры, сеттеры
 */
}
```

`

`InitIndex`:

`

```
@ManagedBean    
@ViewScoped    
public class InitIndex implements Serializable {    

private List<Response> resps = null;    
private ResponseDAO myRespDAO;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    myRespDAO = new ResponseDAO();
    resps = getResps();  
}

/**
 * @return the resps
 */
public List<Response> getResps() {
    //return new ConnectWithDB().getResponses();
    return myRespDAO.getResponses();  
}

/**
 * @param resps the resps to set
 */
public void setResps(ArrayList<Response> resps) {
    this.resps = resps;
}
}
```

`

И, собственно, класс `ResponseDAO`, в котором записывается отзыв и получаем список отзывов. Здесь-то, думаю, и кроется ошибка...

```
`    

public class ResponseDAO implements AutoCloseable {

private final Session session;

public ResponseDAO() {
    this.session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(); //Создание hibernate сессии
}

//добавить отзыв пользователя в БД
public void addResponse(int userId, String text){
    //создаю объект Отзыв
    Response resp = createResponse(text, userId);
    Transaction tx = null;

    try { 
        //записываю объект
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(resp);
        session.flush();

        tx.commit();
    }         catch (Exception e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }
}

//создать объект отзыв  
public Response createResponse(String text, int userId) {
    Response resp = new Response();
    resp.setText(text);

    Users user2 = (Users)session.createQuery("from Users where id = :paramId")
            .setParameter("paramId", userId).list().get(0);

    resp.setUsers(user2);
    resp.setDate(new java.util.Date());
    return resp;
}

//Получение списка отзывов
public List<Response> getResponses() { 
    List<Response> resp = session.createQuery("FROM Response ORDER BY date DESC").list();
    return resp;
}


@Override
public void close() {
    if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
        session.close();
    }
}
}
`
```

Comment: У вас один компонент помечен как @ Named, а другой как @ ManagedBean. Попробуйте привести всё к едином виду - @ ManagedBean.

Comment: @bobzer, не помогло :(

Comment: проверьте, что аннотации ManagedBean, SessionScoped и ViewScoped - все импортированы из пакета javax.faces.bean. Попробуйте поставить SessionScoped вместо ViewScoped. Попробуйте отследить под отладкой в каком порядке вызываются методы, вызываемые на странице (либо добавьте в них трассировку и посмотрите в логах)

Comment: @bobzer, проверила, откуда импортировала аннотации, действительно - `SessionScoped`  было взято из javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped, исправила как надо. Также, избавилась от аннотации `@Named`. Ничего не изменилось... Буду более тщательно отлаживать.